# Passing parameters to Facebook App Links in Android

Tags: java, android, facebook, sdk

I just began implementing Facebook App Linking into my application. I have got my app ID and app link URL from Facebook and I can share links from my app.

I have set up the necessary intent-filter in my AndroidManifest file:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="customscheme"/>
</intent-filter>
```

The app URL is also set up correctly: `customscheme://card/`

Tapping the link in the Facebook app correctly opens my application, so far so good.

What I want to do is when the user clicks the Facebook link, it passes a parameter to my application so that it will know which card it should display. For example: `customscheme://card/48156848`

Currently I am only able to show the activity which has the intent filter and I am not able to extract the necessary parameter from the intent.

Does anyone know a solution for this?